# Pandas построчное объединение таблиц

Tags: python, pandas

Просьба, подсказать, возможно ли построчно объединять несколько df, например имеется 2 df с общими id

1df

```
   ID  QW ER TY UI IO OP
   112 11 23 45 56 76 78
   113 12 45 67 57 75 57
   114 56 75 57 57 87 90
```

2df

```
ID   NM HJ KL
112  56 67 54
113  34 45 56
114  12 41 98
```

объединить нужно к следующему ввиду, например при вызове ID 112

```
ID  QW ER TY UI IO OP
112 11 23 45 56 76 78
ID  NM HJ KL
112 56 67 54
113 12 45 67 57 75 57
114 56 75 57 57 87 90
```

соответсвенно при вызове других id также вставлять строки из df2 с общим id на последующие строки в df1

Comment: Можете уточнить суть вопроса? То что вы привели в вопросе как ожидаемый результат - не является DataFrame? У фрейма может быть только один заголовок (имена столбцов)

Comment: @MaxU
вопрос, возможно ли выполнить в Pandas подобное? ожидаемый результат желательно как DataFrame. Идея, при прощелкивания(вызова) id прописывались строки из 2df, df имеют только общий id,
а если объединить 2 df в одну большую таблицу и при вызове id преобразовывать в данный результат, так возможно сделать?

Comment: Я не понимаю что значит "преобразовывать в данный результат". Вам надо вывести на печать строки из двух разных по структуре DF в нужном порядке?

Comment: @xcplat Что вы в итоге будете делать с полученным результатом? Будете ли обращаться потом как с табличкой (а это не табличка это непонятно что получается)? Или только куда-то печатать/выводить (куда)?

Comment: 1таблица будет выводится в веб, соответсвенно при выборе строки отображать подстроки из 2ой таблице, пытаюсь через Pandas составить таблицу с подстроками объедения  два df

Comment: @xcplat через `Pandas` не получится - у вас в середине таблицы что, ещё одна строка с заголовками таблицы должна быть? Я бы предложил лучше справа эти столбцы приделать в виде дополнительных колонок. Какой смысл располагать не связанные колонки под уже имеющимися? Или колонки `NM HJ KL` на самом деле имеют какую-то связь с `QW ER TY`?

Comment: @CrazyElf благодарю, к сожалению, нет, не имеют общую связь, варианты с объединением и/или формированием дочерней таблицы рядом уже использовал, была мысль сделать как подстроку формирующаяся при выборе строки

Comment: @xcplat Но вы же понимаете, что после этой вставленной строки у вас дальше идут строки, которые относятся к первоначальной таблице и первоначальным заголовкам? Это просто ерунда какая-то получается. Нужно это где-то на уровне html-я тогда формировать, какую-то врезку делать или ещё что-то дизайнерское. С точки зрения именно табличного представления это что-то непонятное вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил вам лучше через `join` (с параметром `left`) сформировать таблицу такого вида:

```
ID  QW ER TY UI IO OP NM HJ KL
112 11 23 45 56 76 78 56 67 54
113 12 45 67 57 75 57
114 56 75 57 57 87 90
```

Так в принципе можно сделать, хотя пустые места придётся либо сначала `NA` заполнить и при выводе в `html` потом данные в строки преобразовать из `NA` в пробелы, либо сразу все числа перевести в строки и тогда можно прямо пробелы в строках иметь.

А в том виде как вы хотите сформировать таблицу не получится - у таблицы не может быть в середине ещё одна строка с заголовками столбцов. А даже если она и могла бы быть, это всё-равно какая-то ерунда, потому что дальше то идут строки у которых заголовки от изначальной таблички и с точки зрения представления информации это что-то непонятное получается.